# Use the PR author's name as an environment in github workflow

Tags: github, github-actions

There are several people working on the same repository and all of them have AWS accounts. For each person our repo has github environment created with person's AWS SECRETS. Is there way to dynamically get PR's author name and use it as environments name for the workflow ?Given that each github environment has the same name as the contributors.

```
jobs:
  job_name:
    environment: PR_AUTHORS_NAME_HERE
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the needed solution by using `github expressions`:

```
jobs:
  build:
    environment: ${{ github.actor }}_environment
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
```

Comment: `${{ github.actor }}` doesn't not always return the author of the pull request or rather the last person to interact with it. For instance if someone else on the team opened the PR and added a label the actor is now the person that added the label instead of the account that opened the pull request.

Answer (score 1):

You can use those github parameter

`${{ github.triggering_actor }}` or `${{ github.actor }}`

**NOTE:** For all GitHub variables

```
- name: Show GitHub context   
  env: 
    GITHUB_CONTEXT: ${{ toJson(github) }}   
  run: echo "$GITHUB_CONTEXT"
  shell: bash
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the pull request author with `{{ github.event.pull_request.user.login }}`.

You can use it like the following:

```yaml
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      PR_AUTHOR: ${{ github.event.pull_request.user.login }}
    steps:
      - name: script
        run: |
          echo "PR author: $PR_AUTHOR"
        shell: bash
```

Comment: The question was about getting [github environments](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/environments) and not about [github environment variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/environment-variables)